# Pagination only showing first page of products; after page 1, getting "Warning: mysqli_query(): Empty query" error

Tags: php, mysql, pagination, limit

When I click on the next link or any page after page 1, I get the following error:

> Warning: mysqli_query() [function.mysqli-query]: Empty query

I am currently trying to view the products by group_id, here is my query:

```
if (isset($_GET['grpid']) && is_numeric($_GET['grpid']) ) {
$grpid = (int) $_GET['grpid'];
if ($grpid > 0) { // Overwrite the query:
$q = "SELECT company.co_id, co_name, category.cat_id, cat_name, prod_name, prod_desc, prod_tag, prod_id, prod_img FROM company, product, category WHERE company.co_id = product.co_id AND category.cat_id = product.cat_id AND product.group_id = $grpid ORDER BY company.co_name ASC, product.prod_name ASC";
}
```

}

I think it may be something to do with this, because if I add in the group table to the query, by adding `group.group_id, group_name` after the `SELECT` clause and `group.group_id = product_group_id` after the `WHERE` clause, I get the following error:

> Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'group WHERE

I hope I have given enough information, my database is 4 tables:

```
product
  prod_id
  co_id
  cat_id
  grp_id
  prod_name
  prod_tag
  prod_desc
  prod_img
company
  co_id
  co_name
  co_img
grp
  grp_id
  grp_name
category
  cat_id
  cat_name
```

### Update

OK my query is exactly this:

```
if (isset($_GET['grpid']) && is_numeric($_GET['grpid']) ) {
$grpid = (int) $_GET['grpid'];
if ($grpid > 0) { // Overwrite the query:
$q = "SELECT company.co_id, co_name, grp.grp_id, grp_name, category.cat_id, cat_name, prod_name, prod_desc, prod_tag, prod_id, prod_img FROM company, product, category, grp WHERE company.co_id = product.co_id AND category.cat_id = product.cat_id AND product.grp_id = $grpid ORDER BY company.co_name ASC, product.prod_name ASC LIMIT $start, $display";
}
```

}

which is then immediately followed by:

```
$r = mysqli_query($dbc,$q) or die("Error: ".mysqli_error($dbc));
```

Which is the line the error points to:

> Warning: mysqli_query() [function.mysqli-query]: Empty query in

I am afraid I do not know how to print out the sql and feed it directly back in?

If I don't use pagination then all of the intended products do show; the problem occurs when I am on any page other than the first page.

### UPDATE 2

If I set the query to run by commenting out the if tags surrounding it, the error message changes to this:

> Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ORDER BY company.co_name ASC, product.prod_name ASC LIMIT 5, 5' at line 1

Does this shed any more light on the subject?

### UPDATE 3 - solved!

Simple simple problem in the end, many thanks to BugFinder and the others who got my brain thinking about the issue properly.

The problem was that I wasn't passing the variable through to the corresponding pages when creating the url, it read:

```
echo '<a href="browse_products.php?&s=' . ($start + $display) . '&p=' . $pages . '">Next</a>';
```

But by adding "grpid=1" to make it read:

```
echo '<a href="browse_products.php?grpid=1&s=' . ($start + $display) . '&p=' . $pages . '">Next</a>';
```

It has solved all of my problems!

THANK YOU GUYS, it is hard for a designer to think about programming the way programmers do, you have literally saved me days and days, great stuff!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

group is a reserved word which is why it would complain. try referencing it as `group` with the quotes.

Comment: OK I have renamed the table to "grp" so the word "group" does not appear anywhere in my query, but I am still getting the same error.
    Warning: mysqli_query() [function.mysqli-query]: Empty query
Thanks for helping me with this

Comment: If you print out the sql rather than run  it in your page, and then feed it direct into mysql do you get the query results you expected?  (Also you didnt include the table group in the sql you presented, I was working on that, assuming it was part of the reason your query wasnt working)

Comment: I have responded by editing my question above, thanks again, Phil

Comment: echo $q; just display the sql to the page so you can check and confirm it has substituted your variables properly

Comment: OH! Question. You only set $q if you have a grpid, what happens if you dont? is this possibly why you get the empty query?

Comment: The url currently reads:
    ...browse_items.php?grpid=1
If I change the end of the url so it reads
    ...browse_items.php
Then I get the error mentioned above, so yes, if I don't set a grpid on the url it returns the error, does this help your thinking?

Comment: I have added
    echo $g;
Now it prints out the query on the first page as it is typed in the script, but I am still getting the error on subsequent pages, with no printout of the query.

Comment: Yes, Your problem is without a gprid, you havent told it what to do, at all, hence your query is empty. as $q is only set if grpid is set. You need either to skip the whole query/display part without an id, or do something else - without context cant offer much more

Comment: OK thank you for your help and pointing me in the right direction, you've been invaluable, cheers, Phil

Comment: One more question, the database knows how many products are in the group, the count code that I am using is:
     $q = "SELECT COUNT(prod_id) FROM product WHERE product.grp_id = 1";
 $r = @mysqli_query ($dbc, $q);
 $row = @mysqli_fetch_array ($r, MYSQLI_NUM);
 $records = $row[0];

and is working correctly, so I don't understand that even though the $grpid is set at 1, that the other pages are still returning an error?

Which topics do I need to read up on to solve this?

Comment: Without code its hard to guess, but the first guess would be you arent passing the grpid to the other pages.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$q = "SELECT c.co_id, c.co_name, cat.cat_id, cat.cat_name, p.prod_name, p.prod_desc, p.prod_tag, p.prod_id, p.prod_img FROM company AS c, product AS p, category AS cat WHERE c.co_id = p.co_id AND cat.cat_id = p.cat_id AND p.group_id = $grpid ORDER BY c.co_name ASC, p.prod_name ASC";
```

Comment: Hey thanks for responding so quickly, I tried but am getting the same result, I forgot to say I also had limit on the end of the query which was working fine. The error is pointing to this line
    $r = mysqli_query($dbc,$q) or die("Error: ".mysqli_error($dbc));

Answer (score 1):

The reason your are getting Warning: mysqli_query() [function.mysqli-query] error is because the query is in `if` block and `mysql_query()` is outside.

Therefore I am guessing `mysql_query()` is called whether `$q` is defined or not. So when it is not defined you are getting `Warning: mysqli_query() [function.mysqli-query]:`

Comment: Yes, the url on the second page loses the "grpid=1" value but it does have the correct limit code attached:

    http://localhost/armex/browse_airguns.php?s=5&p=5

So how to I pass the grpid value to the other pages, what do you recommend I read on up to do this? I am eager to figure it out for myself, I have had a lot fo help so far from BugFinder especially

Comment: The easiest way would be to add the grpid to your query string. Or maybe you should handle a query without grpid.